# Preserving state of button when navigating to other pages

Tags: flutter, dart, state

How can i preserve the state of my favourites button after navigating to another page?

Currently, tapping the favourites button fills the icon and adds the store to a favourites page. However, when I switch pages and come back to the original explore page, the button is reset and no longer filled (the store stays in the fav page). Something i noticed is that the page refreshes itself when i navigate back.

1. How can I preserve the state of my button?
2. Upon hot reloading, whatever that was previously saved in favourites is no longer displayed in the favourites page. How should I resolve this?

I tried using IndexedStack to preserve the state of my different pages but it doesn't register the favourite function (tapping the button fills the icon but does not add the store to the page).

Would really appreciate some help or guidance to set me on the right path.

Here are some snippets of code:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _children = [
    Explore(),
    Browse(),
    FavouritesPage(),
    Settings(),
  ];

  //might have to maintain the state of the red hearts here as well...

  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => FavModel(),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: _children[_currentIndex], //how to use indexed stack?
        bottomNavigationBar: botNavBar(),
      ),
    );
  }

  BottomNavigationBar botNavBar() {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[50],
      onTap: onTabTapped,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.orange[400],
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey[700],
      currentIndex: _currentIndex,
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.explore),
          title: Text(
            'Explore',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.list),
          title: Text(
            'Browse',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
          title: Text(
            'Favourites',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
          title: Text(
            'Settings',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the code for my explore page:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[50],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(
          child: RichText(text: TextSpan(
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 34.0,
              fontFamily: 'Bebas',
            ),
            children: <TextSpan>[
              TextSpan(text: 'No', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              TextSpan(text: 'FOMO', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange[200]))
            ]
          )),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 30.0),

            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'What\'s hot!',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontFamily: 'Bebas',
                        fontSize: 26.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),

                  Spacer(),

                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          'Show All',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            fontFamily: 'Bebas',
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Icon(Icons.arrow_right, color: Colors.black)
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),

            //after what's hot, still part of column

            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 265.0,
                child:
                    WhatsHot(), //obviously this part would have to be based on location
              ),
            ),

            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Text(
                  'Near you',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontFamily: 'Bebas',
                      fontSize: 26.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),

            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 265.0,
                child:
                    NearBy(), //obviously this part would have to be based on location
              ),
            ),

            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Text(
                  'Your Favourites',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontFamily: 'Bebas',
                      fontSize: 26.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),

            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 265.0,
                child: Fav(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to put your app state in a global class or a global static variable.

Just create a static variable in your main.dart file and it will be visible in all files.